# Marriage problem

Tags: combinatorics

Hall's marriage problem says $\{b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n\}$ and $\{g_1,g_2,\dots,g_n\}$  are $n$ boys and $n$ girls respectively. Let $G_i$=set of girls $b_i$ likes. Then a necessary and sufficient condition for a monogamous marriage to happen such that each $b_i$ gets married to a girl in $G_i$ (a compatible matching) is that for any $1\leq k\leq n$, and any $1\leq i_1< i_2<\dots< i_k\leq n$, cardinality of $G_{i_1} \cup \dots \cup G_{i_k}$ should be bigger than $k$ that is, take any $k$ boys then the total number of girls that these $k$ boys together like should be at least $k$.

There is apparently a version of marriage problem in which one considers both the sets- the set of girls whom each boy likes and set of the boys whom each girl likes. In that case the condition reduces to considering any k boys out of $\lceil n/2 \rceil$ instead of $n$ above.

Can someone tell me a good reference for this or a proof of this?

Comment: Awww... I thought you were actually having a problem with your marriage.

Comment: Is there any change that what you were interested in is the Gale-Shapley "marriage problem?"  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem

Answer (score 3):

I’ve not seen a version that exactly matches this description, but the following comes close. It considers only smaller sets, but it compensates by considering both sets of boys *and* sets of girls.

If $B$ and $G$ are the sets of boys and girls, respectively, for each $b \in B$ let $\overline G(b)$ be the set of girls whom $b$ does *not* like, and for each $g \in G$ let $\overline B(g)$ be the set of boys whom $g$ does not like. (It’s more convenient here to use these rather than $G(b)$ and $B(g)$, the sets of boys or girls liked by an individual, but the two are obviously interchangeable.) Then the boys and girls can be married off iff there do not exist $B_0 \subseteq B$ and $G_0 \subseteq G$ such that $|B_0| + |G_0| > n$, $G_0 \subseteq \bigcap_{b \in B_0} \overline G(b)$, and $B_0 \subseteq \bigcap_{g \in G_0} \overline B(g)$. Clearly if such $B_0$ and $G_0$ did exist, one of them would have to have cardinality at most $\lceil n/2 \rceil$.

Suppose that for each $B_1 \subseteq B$ and $G_1 \subseteq G$ of cardinality at most $\lceil n/2 \rceil$, $\left|\bigcap_{b \in B_1} \overline G(b) \right| < n - |B_1|$ and $\left|\bigcap_{g \in G_1} \overline B(b) \right| < n - |G_1|$. Suppose, to get a contradiction, that $B_0 \subseteq B$ and $G_0 \subseteq G$ are such that $|B_0| + |G_0| > n$, $G_0 \subseteq \bigcap_{b \in B_0} \overline G(b)$, and $B_0 \subseteq \bigcap_{g \in G_0} \overline B(g)$; without loss of generality $|B_0 \le \lceil n/2 \rceil$. But then $\left|\bigcap_{b \in B_0} \overline G(b) \right| < n - |B_0| < |G_0|$, so $G_0 \not\subseteq \bigcap_{b \in B_0} \overline G(b)$.

It only remains to check that the nonexistence of sets $B_0 \subseteq B$ and $G_0 \subseteq G$ such that $|B_0| + |G_0| > n$, $G_0 \subseteq \bigcap_{b \in B_0} \overline G(b)$, and $B_0 \subseteq \bigcap_{g \in G_0} \overline B(g)$ is equivalent to the usual formulation of the marriage condition, but this is pretty straightforward if one thinks in terms of the adjacency matrix of the obvious bipartite graph, as in [this discussion](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/elegant.shtml).